# Ordering System that can accept x number of orders

Tags: java, arrays

I think this system might require an Array since it will be up to the user how many orders he or she will take.

I'm currently creating an assignment for our class and we have not yet discussed arrays, I just recently read about it on  Google.

The system will ask the customer what order he or she likes using codes like F1 for food1 or D1 for drink1

So i was thinking something like..

```
    int x = 1;
    String[] foodchoice;
    foodchoice = new String[x];
```

Then the system will accept the first value and  assign it to `foodchoice[1]` the system will now ask if the customer wants to order again and if yes I will simply put `x++` so that   the next info will be added to `foodchoice[2]`..

Im really not sure how to use array yet and by the time I try to check the the info for each `foodchoice` like..

```
    if(foodchoice[1]=="f1")
    {
      System.out.print("You ordered food1");
    }
```

the system crashes and `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` at that `if` line..

help please :c

Comment: Arrays are only good when you have a fixed size of items. Try using a list.

Comment: If you don't know the length of your array in advance, you should work with List (and ArrayList). Java contrary to other languages won't augment the lenght of your array after instanciation.

Comment: AND NEVER COMPARE STRINGS WITH `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int x = 1;
String[] foodchoice;
foodchoice = new String[x];
```

Here you have fixed the dimension of your array to one element.

Arrays begin always by `index=0` so this will work `foodchoice[0]`.

When you do `foodchoice[1]`or 2 and higher,this is not possible because there is no place in RAM for this element , memory is not allocated for it.

I suggest that you use collections , such as `arraylist` or `hashmap` ,it increments automatically and is dynamic not like arrays which you need always to give a fixed dimension.

Use arraylist 
 like this :

```
ArrayList<String> foodchoice  = new ArrayList<String>();
foodChoice.add(firstValue);
foodChoice.add(secondValue);
foodChoice.get(0);//get the first value
```

Comment: going to be reading about ArrayList now. Just to verify, so every time the customer orders something, I'll just put in `foodchoice.add(firstValue)`? then if I am to call the information in this array like the name and price of `foodchoice(1)` I will put in `foodchoice.get(1)`?

Comment: by the way sir.. I'm using `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Food Code")` and storing it in the `arrayList` as the first `foodchoice` and if the customer wants to order again.. it is going to be in the second `foodchoice` then later.. after the customer is done ordering, the system will display the ordered items by calling the items in the `arrayList`

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in java like many other languages are 0-indexed. Thus for an array of size 1 like in your case the biggest index you can have is 0 and `foodchoices[1]` really is `OutOfBounds`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because array indexes start with 0. So `new String[1]` creates an array with the length 1. Valid indexes are 0 <= index < 1 -> only 0 is valid.

Also, arrays are a very bad choice here since arrays don't grow easily. Use a collection type instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array = new String[x]
```

defines array, which index starts from 0 to x-1

You need to add elements with `index 0` i.e., start with `x = 1` and assign value to `foodchoice[x-1]`. after incrementing also assign value to `foodchoice[x-1]`.

Definitely this won't crash.